# Prerender.io how to enable cache?

Tags: angular, prerender

I managed to install prerender locally. It all works well, all pages are prerendered properly but it always takes 5-10 seconds. Does anyone know a  good resource to implement caching on locally installation of Prerender?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you are using our [current master branch](https://github.com/prerender/prerender), there are already some cache plugins in the `plugins/` directory. If you are on the [chrome branch](https://github.com/prerender/prerender/tree/chrome), we haven't ported those caching plugins over yet, but it should be pretty easy if you wanted to port them over yourself.